# ImportError: No module named django.core

Tags: python, django

Good day. 
I changed my Python installation from 32 bit to 64 bit, after that my DJANGO stopped working. I searched the internet and finally added django to my site-packages and added django-admin.py to my path. Now,

> import django

Works. But

> django-admin.py startproject wwwroot

Doesn't work.

It throws an exception:

> ImportError: No module named django.core

Or could it be that there are complications with the former version of Python installed? 
How do I solve this

Comment: You need to reinstall Django for your new python version, not mess about with paths.

Comment: I second @DanielRoseman's comment, but suggest you also look into working with virtual environments.

Comment: It seems Django is already installed @DanielRoseman cos I'm getting "requirement is already satisfied"

Comment: Thanks @nimasmi, I'll consider looking into that